GCP endpoint - authentication
I am trying to setup GCP endpoints which is internally target to K8s ingress service.
My openapi.yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
  title: "Endpoints Example"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "api.endpoints.testproj.cloud.goog"
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
schemes:
- "http"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "api.endpoints.testproj.cloud.goog"
  target: "10.200.140.51" (Ingress LB IP ) 
security:
- google_service_account: []
paths:
  "/":
    get:
      description: "Echo back a given message."
      operationId: "echo"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success."
          schema:
            type: string
        400:
          description: "The data structure is invalid or missing."

securityDefinitions:
  google_service_account:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "test@testproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test@testproj.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

Issue is- authentication is not working
curl api.endpoints.testproj.cloud.goog working fine without authentication.
What the issue ?

If you are facing issues with authentication for GCP endpoints that are targeting k8s service you need to make sure whether the IAM roles and permissions for the service account which are trying to access the endpoints are correctly configured. Also please refer to the Roles that control access to services.

Also you can try implementing the Endpoint Auth using a custom header "Authorization" and also you can retrieve that header as mentioned below:
String Auth = req.getHeader("Authorization");
Additionally,GKE has adopted the new auth plugin architecture for the kubernetes. Refer to this document for more information.

Issue is not with Authentication but authentication implementation. After adding security and security definition , still gcp endpoint is open.

The OpenAPI document appears correct but you've not demonstrated that (a) this has been applied to your project; (b) the curl command succeeds without auth. Please consider updating your question with these facts gcloud endpoints services describe ... etc.

Did you have time to check mine and community member's comment? It helped you to solve your problem?
